# Initial scale setting override media query?

Tags: javascript, css

First I have this media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

    activate style A
 }
```

It worked find like it should.(My iphone 6 wont activate style A)

Then I have this function to change viewport setting when the page loads:

```
function changeViewportMeta() {
    var x = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]')
     if (screen.width < 320){
      x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=0.59");
      } else if(screen.width < 380){
         x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=0.63");
          }else if(screen.width < 430){
          x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=0.70");
             }else if(screen.width < 650){
            x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=0.80");
               }else if(screen.width <750){
              x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=0.90");
                 }else if(screen.width >=750){
                    x.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0");
                   }
        }
```

I "bind" the function by `<body onload="changeViewportMeta()">`

After this it seems like the media query cannot function good anymore.Now if I use my Iphone landscape view I can activate the style A. It kinda worked out fine but it is not I expected. How to fix this?

Comment: check here for Iphone6 specific css media queries http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/  -- the iphone6 has Resolution 750 x 1334 pixels (~326 ppi pixel density) hence why (min-width: 1000px) works in landscape mode

Comment: also check here to dynamically change viewport as you need to add the script in the HEAD of the document rather than ONLOAD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523996/how-to-set-viewport-dynamically