# How to scale only desktop page of a responsive site with viewport meta tag?

Tags: javascript, java, php, css, meta

I want below meta tag to work only in desktop of a responsive site? I dont want it to affect mobile part. How can I do it?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=0.80">
```

Comment: You should take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523996/how-to-set-viewport-dynamically

Comment: I tried below, but it didnt work. Maybe I missed something.

<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=0.80">
<script>
if (screen.width > 768) {
    var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content','width=768');
}
</script>

Comment: I hope my answer will help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like [How to set viewport dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523996/how-to-set-viewport-dynamically) :

```
<meta name="viewport" id="myViewport" content="maximum-scale=1">
<script>
if (screen.width > 768) {
    var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
    mvp.setAttribute('content','maximum-scale=0.80');
}
</script>
```

PS : you can find some generic screen widths on the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) site for example.

Comment: Many, many, too many thanks :) It has worked same as I wanted.

Comment: Thanks again for additional information about Bootstrap.

Comment: Glad to help you ;-)