# setting viewport content width by javascript, does it change the whole content?

Tags: javascript, viewport

From threads like this: [How to set viewport dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523996/how-to-set-viewport-dynamically) I know how to set the width of the viewport content by javascript.

My question is:
If I have this meta tag:

```
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

and change it like this:

```
document.getElementById("myViewport").setAttribute("content","width=500px");
```

Will this delete the user-scalable=no?

Comment: Yes, you pass the whole value on setAttribute, to put it back you need to rebuild the whole string that you send as value

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.